# WPF Navigate to other page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to just navigate between pages

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void RouteItems(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
        nav.Navigate(new ItemsPage());
    }
}
```

GetNavigationService returns null

```
<Window x:Class="Special.MainWindow"
        Name="Window"                  
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Special"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized">

<Button Content="Go" Click="RouteItems"/>
</Window>
```

I don't want to use other method (changing Content).

EDIT

this.NavigationService is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to, first add a `Frame` to your Xaml:

```
<Grid >
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Frame x:Name="MainFrame"></Frame>
    <Button Content="Go" Click="RouteItems" Grid.Row="1"/>

</Grid>
```

then after you add your xaml pages, use the MainFrame to navigate:

```
 private void RouteItems(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Page1.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

Comment: You can read more about navigation and navigation service from here :
http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation

Comment: of course it won't work, MainWindow is a window, not a Page navigation is done from a Page to another Page, besides to go Back you could use the MainFrame.NavigationService.GoBack(); but make sure there a page to goback to, (use MainFrame.NavigationService.CanGoBack bool)